# Perform a function over some time, with time elapsed as parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I want to perform something over several seconds, with the time elapsed as a parameter (specifically, lerp a configured value for an external hardware device). What's a straightforward way to achieve this? I'm a bit lost among all the ways C# can do threading and timers.

This is what I have so far, but it seems clunky, and likely wrong.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var timeToRun = 5000; // in milliseconds
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        var elapsedTime = e.SignalTime - startTime;
        var normalizedTime = elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds / timeToRun;
        someValue = Lerp(from, to, normalizedTime);
    };
    timer.Start();
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(timeToRun);
    timer.Stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a simple way with async method:

```
async Task Loop(int timeInMs, int iterationTimeInMs)
{
    for (int current = 0; current < timeInMs; current += iterationTimeInMs)
    {
        await Task.Delay(iterationTimeInMs);
        var normalizedTime = current / (double)timeInMs;
        someValue = Lerp(from, to, normalizedTime);
    }
}
```

If your `Lerp` can take a long time, then

```
async Task Loop(int timeInMs, int iterationTimeInMs)
{
    Task taskFromLastIteration = null;
    for (int current = 0; current < timeInMs; current += iterationTimeInMs);
    {            
        var delay = Task.Delay(iterationTimeInMs); // start delay now
        if (taskFromLastIteration != null)
            someValue = await taskFromLastIteration;
        await delay;
        var normalizedTime = current / (double)timeInMs;
        taskFromLastIteration = Task.Run(() => Lerp(from, to, normalizedTime));
    }
    if (taskFromLastIteration != null)
        someValue = await taskFromLastIteration;
}
```